# Getting android camera2 preview frames without lagging the screen preview

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

In the original (now deprecated) camera API, we used to be able to get preview frames in the Camera.PreviewCallback and be able to process it (taking possibly very long) and release the buffer to be able to receive another frame, without lagging the screen preview, with some code like the following:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            (... do some slow processing ...)
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data); // free the buffer to be able
                                               // to process another frame
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

The API would only callback with a new frame if there was another buffer available to receive it, without lagging the screen preview.

I'm trying to replicate the same behaviour on the new Camera2 API, but I can't find a way to do it without lagging the screen preview. If I add a second target (same resolution as the screen one, YUV_420_888) to the preview request:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewImageReader.getSurface());
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
    Arrays.asList(surface, previewImageReader.getSurface()), ...
```

the screen preview will lag, even if I just close the image as soon as I get it:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    reader.acquireNextImage().close();
}
```

What's the correct way to use Camera2 to emulate the original camera API behaviour (i.e having a new buffer whenever one is free and not slowing the screen preview)?

Update: In case anyone is wondering how the rest of the code looks like, it is just a modified version of the standard android-camera2Basic sample, [here's what I've changed](https://github.com/silvaren/android-Camera2Basic/commit/babbc06485b9cdef11444fd7f76ae22af3590de6).

Comment: Just closing the image immediately should be plenty fast.  What resolution and format are you using for the previewImageReader? What hardware level of device are you testing on?

Comment: It is clearly at least half the speed of the normal preview (i.e. just the screen surface as target configured). Here are the details: resolution 960x720, YUV_420_888 format, LEGACY level device (a Moto G 2nd Gen).

Comment: @EddyTalvala I also just added what I've changed to the standard android-camera2Basic sample in the question so people can try themselves/see where is the problem.

Comment: Did you find out how to fix it?

Comment: @nhoxbypass nope :( ended up working in another project

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still interested.

Create a `SurfaceTextureListener` and call your async function from the `onSurfaceTextureUpdated` method. I have used this successfully when checking frames for barcodes with the BarcodeDetection API and the Camera 2 API.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your async function. I need to do something similar with face detection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of an async function launched from the `onSurfaceTextureUpdated` method. If you only want to run one async task in the background at a time, you can use a flag to check if the previous task has completed.

```
private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
    = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

    boolean processing;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        openCamera(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        configureTransform(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        if (processing) {
            return;
        }

        processing = true;

        Bitmap photo = mTextureView.getBitmap();

        new ImageTask(photo, new ImageResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinished() {
                    processing = false;
                }
            }).execute();
    }
};

private interface ImageResponse {
    void processFinished();
}

private class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception> {
    private Bitmap photo;
    private ImageResponse imageResponse;
    ImageTask(Bitmap photo, ImageResponse imageResponse) {
        this.photo = photo;
        this.imageResponse = imageResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do background work here
        imageResponse.processFinished();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {

    }
}
```